# Linux PowerShell The term 'sqlpackage' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet

Tags: sql, linux, powershell, sqlpackage

Until now, every thing was ok with this command in PowerShell. But after update/reboot i'have troubles...

```
sqlpackage /a:Extract /scs:"Data Source='$sourceServer';Initial Catalog='$sourceDatabase'; User ID='$sqlUser';Password='$sqlPass'" /tf:$dacpac /p:DacApplicationName=Ubiquite /p:IgnorePermissions=True /p:IgnoreUserLoginMappings=True >> $log
```

This same command in bash work perfectly but powerShell send this

```
The term 'sqlpackage' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,...
```

I have allready reinstall sqlpackage as [Download and install sqlpackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15#get-sqlpackage-net-core-for-linux)

I will apreciate some help.

Comment: I am using this powershell script from months in order to update several azure databases from linux vm in azure with extract and publish DACPAC's

Comment: Check if the path to sqlpackage.exe is in your `PATH` environment variable

Comment: If I run slqpackage in bash, works perfectly.... PowerShell won't execute it....

Comment: Meanwhile I launch in with full path:     **/home/SQLPACKAGEPATH/sqlpackage/sqlpackage /a:Publish /tcs:"Data Source=....**. And work fine